# how to install ffmpeg php on localhost and online server?

Tags: php

I want to use **ffmpeg** for creating a thumbnail images, when the user upload the video.

Is there a way to do this natively with ffmpeg ?

Comment: What is your question? What makes you believe it's not possible. Please reference the official documentation to back-up your claims.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in two ways:

1. Use executable ffmpeg (ffmpeg.exe) and run ffmpeg commands using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or passthru, etc in php or
2. Use [PHP-FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)